# get value from label using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can i get the content of a label with for attribute using jquery ? 
in this exemple i want to get "Male"

```
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
```

Comment: `$('label[for="male"]').text()`

Comment: The same way as you get the content of any other element. What makes you think `<label>` is any different?

Comment: Do you want to get the content of the label, or do you want the value of the input that it's a label for? The title says **value**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method to catch label with attribute

```
$('label[for="male"]').text();
```

`.text()` will give the content in label in text form. In case in future you will use any kind of html tag in it then you can use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to get the value in html form

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function along with the appropriate selector to target the `for` attribute specifically :

```
// This will retrieve the text for any label with the for attribute set to "male"
$('label[for="male"]').text();
```

You can [see a simple example of this here](http://jsbin.com/perapo/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
   $('input').on('change', function() {
   alert($("label").text()); 
});
```

Here is an working [example](http://jsbin.com/wenezehuzi/1/edit?html,js,output).